# Modification of the list items in the loop (python)

Tags: python, loops, items

I'm trying to modify items in a list using a for loop, but I get an error (see below). Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# *-* coding: utf8 *-*

data = []
data.append("some")
data.append("example")
data.append("data")
data.append("here")

for item in data:
    data[item] = "everything"
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testy.py", line 11, in <module>
    data[item] = "everything"
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for i in xrange(len(data)):
    data[i] = "everything"
```

The basic problem you're having is that when you write `data[i]`, with `data` being a list, the `i` needs to be an integer, a numerical index into the list. But in the loop

```
for item in data
```

`item` is the actual thing that's in the list, i.e. a string, not the numerical index of the thing. `xrange` is an iterator that produces numbers instead of the values in the list, so you can use that.

An alternative would be

```
for i, _ in enumerate(data):
    data[i] = "everything"
```

The `enumerate` function gives you an iterator over tuples of the form `(index, item)`, so all you need to do is take the index and forget about the item. I'm not sure that one way or the other (`enumerate` or `xrange`) will be significantly faster or better, since I think lists store their length in a variable so it can be quickly accessed without counting through the list elements.

However, if you need the old list value to compute the new list value, the `enumerate` way will probably be slightly faster because you avoid making Python look up the element in the list:

```
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    data[i] = func(item)
```

This sort of thing is better expressed as a list comprehension, though:

```
data = [func(item) for item in data]
```

When you do this, Python will go through each item in `data`, apply the function to it, and construct a new list from the results automatically, so you don't need to worry about putting the result of `func(item)` in the right place in the list. Your original example could actually be expressed as

```
data = ["everything" for item in data]
```

Comment: It looks a little strange (or workaround), but it works correctly. I did not know that the overriding items (in list) must be given their ID. Thanks.

Comment: @sigo: that is actually not a workaround at all, it is the 100% correct and perfectly normal way to do this sort of task (but note what I said about list comprehensions).

Comment: In this particular case, the list comprehension could be replaced by the faster `data = ["everything"] * len(data)`.

Comment: A side note on memory consumption and list comprehensions: this will require (temporarily) the memory to store the old `data` and the new `data`. Hence, for large lists, the indexed modification may be preferable.

Answer (score 5):

List items are accessed by integer index, i. e. in your example `data[1] == 'example'`. This is why Python complains when you're using a string as a lookup.

If you want to find an element in a list by its value, you can use `data.index("value")`:

```
data[data.index("some")] = "something else"
```

But if you just want to loop over them, use `enumerate()` as David suggested.

Answer (score 0):

the indexing of a list using integers could be inefficient. It is likely that python stores list elements using linked table with underlying pointers. In this case, to find a specific item, python have to traverse the list until the i-th item.

It is suggested that using the format like this could be efficient:
a[:] = [x*x for x in a]