# Iterating and averaging over some messy data

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have some messy data that I'm passing through a function. The function below tries to take an average. Sometimes items in the list aren't numbers, and will throw an error.

I tried to use regex to replace non numeric characters, but some stuff is still getting through. Any time a bad value shows up (due to messy data) I just want a 0 recorded for that item in the list.

```
def mean(vals):
    if len(vals) == 0:
        return 0.0

    for val in vals:
        val = re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", str(val))
    print vals
    vals = [float(val) for val in vals]
    return sum(vals) / len(vals)
```

I'm printing the list of vals just to see where I'm throwing an error. The last vals list is:

```
['</a>']
```

How is this possible, given I've regexed everything that isn't a number or a period?

Comment: Are you getting this data from an HTML source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an `re.sub`, use `try`/`except`...

```
def mean(vals):
    total = 0.0
    length = 0
    for val in vals:
        try:
            total += float(val)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
             pass
        length += 1
    return total / length if length else 0.0
```

Comment: @ZiyaoWei that's not the way I interpreted *I just want a 0 recorded for that item in the list*

Comment: Mmm, you are right - OP's words and code doesn't match.

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the inconsistency in the code. I didn't want to return 0 for the mean, just 0 for that item, then calculate the mean for all items in list.

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing `vals`'s value by (see [Modification of the list items in the loop (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173915/modification-of-the-list-items-in-the-loop-python))

```
val = re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", str(val))
```

Instead, you could loop through the index of the list and change its content directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing your list in the for loop, you are just setting a variable inside the loop scope that doesn't reflects on the list.

To change your list you should do something like this:

```
>>> vals = [re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", str(val)) for val in vals]
```