# Update specific items within a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following input:

```
'lesson*lesson*practice*lesson*quiz*practice'
```

and here's the desired output:

```
'lesson1*lesson2*practice1*lesson3*quiz*practice2'
```

So if any item repeats in the list, I'd like to append 1,2,3... to the occurrences. To get this done, I came up with the following code:

```
line = 'lesson*lesson*practice*lesson*quiz*practice'
line1 = line

def list_to_dict(li):  
    dct = {}  
    for item in li.split('*'):  
        if dct.has_key(item):  
            dct[item] = dct[item] + 1  
        else:  
            dct[item] = 1  
    return dct

for item in list_to_dict(line).keys():
    counter = 1
    if list_to_dict(line)[item] > 1:
        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(line.split('*')) if x == item]
        for idx, _ in enumerate(line1[indices]):
            line1[idx] = line1[idx] + str(counter)
            counter = counter + 1

print line1
print line
```

But this code gives me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-187-a85290a89eea> in <module>()
      6     if list_to_dict(line)[item] > 1:
      7         indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(line) if x == item]
----> 8         for idx, _ in enumerate(line1[indices]):
      9             line1[idx] = line1[idx] + str(counter)
     10             counter = counter + 1

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not list
```

Would someone please be able to help get the desired output?

If you think my algorithm to achieve this is not good, I'd welcome any new ideas, too.

Comment: What is `for idx, _ in enumerate(line1[indices]):` supposed to do?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `for idx in indices:`

Comment: @LutzHorn: I took the particular piece of code you're tlaking about, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173915/modification-of-the-list-items-in-the-loop-python . This is to replace items within a list.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: I tried what you're saying earlier, and I get the following error: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-200-a67f65e082c3> in <module>()
      7         indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(line.split('*')) if x == item]
      8         for idx in indices:
----> 9             line1[idx] = line1[idx] + str(counter)
     10             counter = counter + 1
     11 

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: So you've copied code you do not understand and ask us to explain it to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try your code but I suspect using a dict will cause ordering problems? Here's a solution:

```
from collections import Counter

def add_counts_to_words(s):
    words = s.split('*')
    totals = Counter(words)
    counts = Counter()
    result = []
    for word in words:
        if totals[word] > 1:
            counts.update([word])
            result.append('%s%d' % (word, counts[word]))
        else: # singleton
            result.append(word)
    return '*'.join(result)

print add_counts_to_words('lesson*lesson*practice*lesson*quiz*practice')
```

Comment: Did it. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying to reinvent [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

But you over overcomplicate your answer

```
from collections import Counter

line = 'lesson*lesson*practice*lesson*quiz*practice'
line_list = line.split('*')

counter = Counter()
output_list = []
for elem in line_list:
    counter.update((elem, 1))
    output_list.append(''.join((elem, str(counter[elem]))))

'*'.join(output_list)
```

Output:

```
'lesson1*lesson2*practice1*lesson3*quiz1*practice2'
```